# Datatable ajax reload table but it reset to default content

Tags: datatable

I am using Datatable 1.10.0

Here is the my code:-

https://jsfiddle.net/a40wrubk/

when I do chrome inspect console log:

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://project.dev/index.php/report_topup_dt?draw…art=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1470796877894".

Success Ajax load

XHR finished loading: GET "http://project.dev/index.php/report_topup_dt?from=2015-01-01&to=2016-12-31"

XHR finished loading: GET "http://project.dev/index.php/report_topup_dt?draw…art=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1470796877895"
```

After you can see after I successfully load the ajax, the last action it do reload the first request again. So my datatable did not get the search filter result.

How do I prevent it load again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After do a few research, I manage to find a reference page.

```
https://coderexample.com/datatable-custom-column-search/
```

I got the wrong concept to do the filter. It has to be inside one datatabase function and initial or else will have the error "Cannot reinitialise DataTable."

What I did is change the type from GET to POST, and set the data parameter.

Here is the solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/t4y4hq6h/1/